# How to change location of Influxdb storage folder?

Tags: linux, influxdb

I've Installed package from the official site by instruction. By default the physical destination of database folder is `/opt/influxdb/shared`.

I've tried to change properties of config file and written it properly. But after that I can't start the influxdb service.

```
[storage]

dir = "/media/alex/Second/InfluxStorage/data/db" //my settings
```

How I can change the default database directory ?

Comment: The problem was solved by changing rights of access to external disk storage(the destination that I want to store influxdb).

Comment: You should write your solution as an official answer for others to enjoy.

Answer (score 29):

**EDIT: This is for InfluxDB v1.x only. It has been reported to not work for InfluxDB v2.x.**

Make a new directory where you want to put your data and set the appropriate permissions, e.g.:

```
mkdir /new/path/to/influxdb
sudo chown influxdb:influxdb influxdb
```

Edit the following **three** lines of your `/etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf` (`/usr/local/etc/influxdb.conf` on macOS) so that they point to your new location:

```
# under [meta]
dir = "/new/path/to/influxdb/meta"

# under [data]
dir = "/new/path/to/influxdb/data"
wal-dir = "/new/path/to/influxdb/wal"
```

Restart the InfluxDB daemon.

```
sudo service influxdb restart  # Ubuntu/Debian
brew services restart influxdb  # macOS/homebrew
```

Done!

In case you want to **move** existing data, just simply copy the existing data (location can be found at `influxdb.conf`; `/var/lib/influxdb` on Ubuntu/Debian) to your new desired location before editing `influxdb.conf` and make sure the new folder has the appropriate permissions/ownership.

There is some information about backups/restores on the [official docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/administration/backup_and_restore/), however just plain copying worked for me.

The above was tested on InfluxDB v1.2 on macOS/Ubuntu/Raspbian.

Comment: moved and cannot find databases. Anyone has a clue?

Comment: @EricWang What version of InfluxDB were you using?

Comment: If you want to copy your existing data, make also sure that you set the permissions and owner for the files correct. Otherwise influxdb won't start. `sudo cp -rp /old/path /new/path` works fine.

Comment: @GustavoBezerra I am using v1.2.2.1. Is there anything to worry about if I would like to move data between different version?

Comment: For the record I just followed these steps for Influxdb 1.7.8 for Windows and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 10):

**For InfluxDB 2.0**:

In InfluxDB 2.0 the data directories are below `~/.influxdbv2` by default.

Actually, there are 2 data storages for [bolt](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/#bolt-path) (various key-value configurations) and [engine](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/#engine-path) (the TSM database).

From the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/#bolt-path), to change the location to the bolt database:

- Default: `~/.influxdbv2/influxd.bolt`
- influxd flag: `influxd --bolt-path=~/.influxdbv2/influxd.bolt`
- Environment variable: `export INFLUXD_BOLT_PATH=~/.influxdbv2/influxd.bolt`
- Configuration file: `bolt-path: /users/user/.influxdbv2/influxd.bolt`

From the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/#engine-path), to change the location to the engine database:

- Default: `~/.influxdbv2/engine`
- influxd flag: `influxd --engine-path=~/.influxdbv2/engine`
- Environment variable: `export INFLUXD_ENGINE_PATH=~/.influxdbv2/engine`
- Configuration file: `engine-path: /users/user/.influxdbv2/engine`

Comment: Default values for Debian & Ubuntu (config.toml):

`bolt-path = "/var/lib/influxdb/influxd.bolt"`

`engine-path = "/var/lib/influxdb/engine"`