# How to change database location of influxDB 2.7 on Linux machine

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, influxdb-2

I'm new to influxdb (2.7) and also no expert with Linux. I am not able to change the location of my database on a RasPi to an external drive.

I tried to follow these steps listed here for influxdb 2:
[Stackoverflow-Change-location-of-influxdb-storage-foider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350290/how-to-change-location-of-influxdb-storage-folder/77081256#77081256)

- change the location to the bolt database
- change the location to the engine database
  Before that i stoped the service.
  When I run this command

```
sudo influxd --bolt-path=/mnt/extDrive/influxdbv/influxd.bolt
```

it says after a second until I stop via Strg+C the following output always showing the last authorization error in kind of a loop:

```
2023-09-11T11:18:25.335563Z info    Welcome to InfluxDB {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "version": "v2.7.0", "commit": "85f725f8b9", "build_date": "2023-04-05T15:32:18Z", "log_level": "info"}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.344449Z info    Resources opened    {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "bolt", "path": "/influxdbv/influxd.bolt"}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.344925Z info    Resources opened    {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "sqlite", "path": "/influxdbv/influxd.sqlite"}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.370683Z info    Using data dir  {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "path": "/root/.influxdbv2/engine/data"}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.370861Z info    Compaction settings {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "max_concurrent_compactions": 2, "throughput_bytes_per_second": 50331648, "throughput_bytes_per_second_burst": 50331648}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.370956Z info    Open store (start)  {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "op_name": "tsdb_open", "op_event": "start"}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.371370Z info    Open store (end)    {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "storage-engine", "service": "store", "op_name": "tsdb_open", "op_event": "end", "op_elapsed": "0.418ms"}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.372083Z info    Starting retention policy enforcement service   {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "retention", "check_interval": "30m"}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.372456Z info    Starting precreation service    {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "shard-precreation", "check_interval": "10m", "advance_period": "30m"}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.377229Z info    Starting query controller   {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "storage-reads", "concurrency_quota": 1024, "initial_memory_bytes_quota_per_query": 9223372036854775807, "memory_bytes_quota_per_query": 9223372036854775807, "max_memory_bytes": 0, "queue_size": 1024}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.395288Z info    Configuring InfluxQL statement executor (zeros indicate unlimited). {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "max_select_point": 0, "max_select_series": 0, "max_select_buckets": 0}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.433135Z info    Starting    {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "telemetry", "interval": "8h"}
2023-09-11T11:18:25.435450Z info    Listening   {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "service": "tcp-listener", "transport": "http", "addr": ":8086", "port": 8086}
2023-09-11T11:18:27.746553Z info    Unauthorized    {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "error": "authorization not found"}
2023-09-11T11:18:31.325028Z info    Unauthorized    {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "error": "authorization not found"}
2023-09-11T11:18:35.757608Z info    Unauthorized    {"log_id": "0kC~GqDl000", "error": "authorization not found"}
```

Does someone know what I am doing wrong? Or is there a guideline saying step by step how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

General questions: Do I need to copy the influxdb folder from /var/lib/influxdb to the external drive including all permissions before running `influxd --bolt-path=`? I tried both with the same result: getting this authorization error.